# babel-istanbul cover exclude file from report but keep to transpile

Tags: mocha.js, code-coverage, ecmascript-6, babeljs, istanbul

My goal is to be able to write src and tests files in es6, all in the same directory (I want my test files to be side-by-side with my source files), and get coverage report with the original files.

The best I can come up with at this point is to have my test files included in the coverage report with the following command:

```
./node_modules/.bin/babel-node node_modules/.bin/babel-istanbul \
    cover \
    node_modules/.bin/_mocha -- 'src/**/*.spec.*.js'
```

I did try using the `cover -x 'src/**/*.spec.*.js'`, it also excludes the files from transpiling and `mocha` then fails to run the tests. For the life of me, I cannot figure out how to do the equivalent of something like this:

```
./node_modules/.bin/babel-node node_modules/.bin/babel-istanbul \
  cover -x 'src/**/*.spec.*.js' \
  node_modules/.bin/_mocha -- --require babel-core/register 'src/**/*.spec.*.js'
```

this will run all my tests fine but has the negative effect of giving me:

```
No coverage information was collected, exit without writing coverage information
```

So I am not too far from what I want, I'm think I'm just missing that last piece there and if somebody can help here, it would be really appreciated.

Regards,
D.

Comment: If someone else ever hits this issue again, I've now moved to the new istanbul tool [nyc](https://www.npmjs.com/package/nyc) which makes this much easier.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Never got the `-x` option to do what I wanted. If you don't mind using an `.istanbul.yml` file this worked for me to get side-by-side tests excluded from coverage reports...

`npm run cover` command:

`babel-node node_modules/.bin/babel-istanbul cover _mocha -- --opts mocha.opts`

`project_dir/mocha.opts` file:

```
src/**/*.test.js
--compilers js:babel-register
--require babel-polyfill
```

`project_dir/.istanbul.yml` file:

```
instrumentation:
  root: src
  include-all-sources: true
  verbose: true
  excludes: ["*.test.js"]
reporting:
  dir: "coverage"
```

Comment: Thanks, but with this, i get: `No coverage information was collected, exit without writing coverage information`

Comment: I took out the `--compiliers js:babel-core/register` and it seems to work. I was blocked so stopped my testings, but I'll work on it a little bit more and see if any other issues come out.

Answer (score 0):

For anyone finding this much later, the stack with `mocha`, `@babel` and `nyc` is much much much much (did I say much?) easier to configure. No more need of that `babel-node`.

`package.json`:

```
{
  ...
  "scripts": {
    "coveralls": "cat reports/coverage/lcov/info | coveralls", // <-- Used on CI
    "coverage": "nyc --report-dir=reports/coverage npm test",
    "test": "mocha \"src/**/*.test.js?(x)\""
  },
  "mocha": {
    "require": [
      "@babel/register",
      ...
    ]
  },
  ...
}
```

and here's an example of my `.nycrc`:

```
{
  "all": true,
  "cache": false,
  "temp-dir": "./reports/nyc_output",
  "check-coverage": false,
  "require": [
    "@babel/register"
  ],
  "exclude": [
    "dist/",
    "reports/",
    "src/**/*.test.js",
    "src/**/*.test.jsx"
  ],
  "extension": [
    ".js",
    ".jsx"
  ],
  "reporter": [
    "cobertura",
    "lcov",
    "html"
  ],
  "watermarks": {
    "statements": [50, 80],
    "lines": [50, 80],
    "functions": [50, 80],
    "branches": [50, 80]
  }
}
```